# graph implementation: variable has initializer but incomplete type

Tags: c++

I am trying to learn C++ and would like to implement some of the algorithms for finding minimum spanning trees in graphs. However, I am having some trouble writing the interface and I don't know where I am going wrong. I get two errors:

error: variable 'Graph::adjIterator it' has initializer but incomplete type

error: expected ',' or ';' before '=' token

graph.h

```
#ifndef GRAPH_H
#define GRAPH_H

#include<vector>

struct Edge {

    int v, w;
    double weight;
    Edge(int v_, int w_, double weight_ = 1) :
            v(v_), w(w_), weight(weight_) {
    }
};

class Graph {
private:
    int Vcnt, Ecnt;
    bool directedGraph;
    struct Node {

        int v;
        Node* next;
        Node(int v_, Node* next_) :
                v(v_), next(next_) {
        }

    };
    std::vector<Node*> adj;     //this is a linked list ! 

public:
    Graph(int V, bool diGraph = false) :
            adj(V), Vcnt(V), Ecnt(0), directedGraph(diGraph) {
        adj.assign(V, NULL);
    }
    int V() {
        return Vcnt;
    }
    int E() {
        return Ecnt;
    }
    bool directed() const {
        return directedGraph;
    }
    void insert(Edge e) {
        int v = e.v;
        int w = e.w;
        adj[v] = new Node(w, adj[v]);
        if (!directedGraph)
            adj[w] = new Node(v, adj[w]);
        Ecnt++;
    }
    bool egde(int v, int w) const;
//void remove(Edge e);
    class adjIterator;
    friend class adjIterator;
};
```

graph.cpp

```
#include "graph.h"

class Graph::adjIterator {
private:
    const Graph & G;
    int v;
    Node* t;
public:
    adjIterator(const Graph& G_, int v_) :
            G(G_), v(v_) {
        t = 0;
    }
    int begin() {
        t = G.adj[v];
        return t ? t->v : -1;
    }
    int nxt() {
        if (t)
            t = t->next;
        return t ? t->v : -1;
    }
    bool end() {
        return t == 0;
    }
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "graph.h"

int main() {
    Graph G(2);
    Edge e(0, 1);
    G.insert(e);
    for(Graph::adjIterator it(G,0) = it.begin(); it != it.end(); it.nxt()) {
        //stuff 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Well what's wrong with it?

Comment: The subject line says what's wrong with it; it's a compilation error, but it would be good if the OP would give the full error, including a line number.

Comment: I get two errors, namely Variable 'Graph::adjIterator it' has initializer but incomplete type and error: expected ',' or ';' before '=' token

Comment: @angry_pacifist: would you modify your question to include the full text of both errors?

Comment: `class Graph::adjIterator {`, I never knew you can do that

Answer (score 2):

You've defined the class 'adjIterator' in a .cpp file, and then tried to use it from a different .cpp file which has only seen the forward declaration in the .h

Also, while this isn't your immediate problem, you have a lot of stuff in your .h file that probably belongs in the .cpp.

Generally you put all your declarations in the .h, and all the implementation in a .cpp.

So a .h might have:

```
class myClass {
  public:
  myClass();
  void someMethod(int argument);
}
```

And then the .cpp would have:

```
myClass::myClass()
{
  //initialise stuff
}

void myClass::someMethod(int argument)
{
  //do something clever
}
```

Comment: do I need to include graph.cpp in the main then? Or should I write the definition of Graph::adjIterator in the graph.h ? thanks

Comment: It's generally bad practice to #include a .cpp file. Generally you would put the declaration in the .h, and the implementation in the .cpp.

Comment: No. You declared that you had a class called 'adjIterator', but you didn't declare the methods, etc.